# How to reinstall Windows Store if it's completely missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

about a year ago, I removed a little too many apps from my Computer with `Remove-AppxPackage`. Since then my Windows Store is missing.

I know I could reinstall the Windows Store by using this command:

```
Get-AppXPackage *WindowsStore* -AllUsers | Foreach {
   Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"
}
```

The thing is, It doesn't even find the package at all, so `Get-AppxPackage *Store* -AllUsers` returns nothing at all.

How can I get my Windows Store back, without reinstalling / updating my OS? (by reinstall I mean a completely new blank installation, by updating an update to a newer version like 1809)

My OS is Windows 10 Version 10.0.14393.0

Note: I also tried the usual stuff like:

- `sfc /scannow`
- `dism /online /cleanup-image /RestoreHealth`

but that also did not work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you still have an ISO for 14393?  If so you can do an in place upgrade to the same version and this will keep your programs and data while replacing the store and other provisioned apps.

Comment: You need to provide a source for the packages you are attempting to install.  You can either do this by using the same ISO you used to install Windows.  Is there a reason you have not installed a single Cumulative update in over 2 years?  You don't indicate, the method you remove the applications originally, but you likely removed the package entirely from your system hence the need for a 1607 ISO.  Much easier to install Windows within a VM, copy the packages, then register them.  Hence the reason this is a duplciate.